# Where to add faqs schema code in this type category pages on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, schema

Where to add faqs schema code in this specific type of editor on WordPress.[this editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGRMl.png)

or i just put the code in end of the bottom content description. and is it important to use div tag around schema code. or i just simply put the schema code.